# Checkbox is Selected but can't able to clicked on it using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On clicking a checkbox, the checkbox is highlighted but its not clicked 
and i don't get  exception .

```
<input name="include_notice" onclick="javascript:TogglePublishDates();" type="checkbox">
```

[image: Picture of highlighted checkbox]

I identify this checkbox with Name and tried using `sendkeysReturn` and `sendKeysEnter`.

**Note:** This test case was running good for quite a long time.No changes were made in Selenium Web driver or Firefox.

Comment: Please try to click two times.

Comment: Also, could you please make sure that you're uniquely identify this particular element?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to click using java script, as shown below:

```
JavascriptExecutor e = (JavascriptExecutor)wd;
e.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.name("include_notice")));
```

If you still observe the inconsistent behavior, you may want to implement the retry mechanism, as shown below:

```
    //1) Finding the check box
    WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.name("include_notice"));
    //2) Checking whether check box is already checked
    if (!checkBox.isSelected()) {
        JavascriptExecutor e = (JavascriptExecutor)wd;
        e.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkBox);
        //3) Checking whether first attempt to check the check box worked
        if (!checkBox.isSelected()) {
            //4) Retrying
            checkBox.click();
        }
    }
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with these below codes:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("include_notice")).click();  //find checkbox element and click on it.
```

Click checkbox using java-script executor.

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.name("include_notice"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkbox);
```

If Checkbox is already selected then use this code.

```
 WebElement checkbox =  driver.findElement(By.name("include_notice"));
 if (!checkBox.isSelected())        //checkbox is not selected then only it will select the checkbox.
 {
     checkBox.click();
     System.out.println(checkbox.isSelected());
 }
```

Comment: Does my explanation of code `helped` you? if it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted`