# How to check the condition, whether the checkbox is clicked or not using java with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

When i tried to check the condition whether the checkbox is clicked or not.
but it displayed only the else(false) part, when the condition is true or false.

Checkbox image:
[image]

`HTML`:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable ui-state-highlight" data-ri="0" data-rk="69022768" role="row" aria-selected="true"> 
    <td class="ui-selection-column" role="gridcell" style="width: 34px; text-align:center"> 
        <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget"> 
            <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"> 
                <input name="identititesSelect:tabView:searchResultsTable_checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
            </div>
```

Here is the below code which i tried:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d1, 30);
              WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-helper-hidden-accessible']/input[@type='checkbox']")));

              if (element.isSelected())
              {
              System.out.println("true");
              }
              else
              {
              System.out.println("false");
              }
```

Comment: Might be duplicate question of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069153/checkbox-is-selected-but-cant-able-to-clicked-on-it-using-selenium/42082127#42082127

Comment: I guess this is because you can apply `isSelected()` to `<input type="checkbox">` or `<input type="radio">` only, but in your case you're trying to handle `<div>` element. I suggest you to check elements' `class` attribute in both "checked" and "unchecked" states- it should be different

Comment: Hi, I can able to click the checkbox using java with selenium, but i couldn't able to check the condition whether the check box is clicked or not

Comment: @Andersson , <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<input name="identititesSelect:tabView:searchResultsTable_checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
</div>  It also having the type = "checkbox"

Comment: @Andersson   Html code for checked: <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable ui-state-highlight" data-ri="0" data-rk="69022768" role="row" aria-selected="true">
<td class="ui-selection-column" role="gridcell" style="width: 34px; text-align:center">
<div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<input name="identititesSelect:tabView:searchResultsTable_checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>

Comment: @Andersson   Html for unchecked:  <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable" data-ri="0" data-rk="69022768" role="row" aria-selected="false">
<td class="ui-selection-column" role="gridcell" style="width: 34px; text-align:center">
<div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<input name="identititesSelect:tabView:searchResultsTable_checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong selector. `XPath` should be as follow:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//div[@class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"]/input[@type="checkbox"]')));
```

You also can check attribute `aria-selected` which is `true` if checkbox selected, and `false` otherwise:

```
WebElement element = d1.findElement(By.xpath("tr[@class='ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable']"));
if (element.getAttribute('aria-selected').equals('true'))
    {
    System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("false");
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code which you given : WebElement element = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable']"));
          if (element.getAttribute("aria-selected").equals("true"))
              {
              System.out.println("true");
              }
              else
              {
              System.out.println("false");
              }                   Still am getting the condition as "false"

Comment: Have you tried your code with `//div[@class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"]/input[@type="checkbox"]` `XPath`?

Comment: I tried with this code but it getting the error as " invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='ui-helper-hidden-accessible'] and input[@type='che‌​ckbox']"

Comment: Did you use exactly `//div[@class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"]/input[@type="che‌​ckbox"]` or `//div[@class='ui-helper-hidden-accessible'] and input[@type='che‌​ckbox']` ?

Comment: while trying the 1st command "//div[@class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"]/input[@type="che‌​‌​ckbox"]"  iam getting the error as "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='ui-helper-hidden-accessible']/input[@type='che‌​‌​ckbox']"}"

Comment: while using this code element.getAttribute("aria-selected") , by default the attribute value returns False even a checkbox is checked.

Comment: Please find the updated code.. Again it goes to the else part only.  when the check box is checked.

Comment: Could you share page `URL` or it is confidential?

Comment: I find the answer by handling the Exception. Thanks for your support.